# Why is my onItemSelectedListener not called in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, listener

I'm using a ListView that is setup like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:longClickable="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

In my code I add an OnItemSelectedListener to the ListView like this:

```
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
getListView().setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

my Activity implements the listener like that:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("Tag", "ListItemSelected: Parent: " + parent.toString() + " View: "
            + view.toString() + " Position: " + " Id: " + id);
}
```

My hope was, that I would see this debug output the moment I click on something in the list. But the debug output is never shown in LogCat.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The [`OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) listens for list item selections and not list item clicks.

A selection in this case could be seen as moving the focus on this item with the device's trackpad.

To get the wanted behavior one must use the [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Comment: I implemented your method but having some issues. The list selector is getting disappeared.

Comment: try to add these attributes to your list view <ListView android:stackFromBottom="true" android:choiceMode="singleChoice" ... this will keep the Item highlighted after you select it, and when you select another item the previous selection will disappear.

Comment: This looks like more of a workaround than a fix.  *Selection* event isn't firing.

Comment: It does seem that way. I'm calling setSelection() and even that doesn't trigger it. :|

Answer (score 4):

It's because you happen to be testing with your fingers on a touch-enabled device. In [touch mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html), there is no focus and no selection. UIs that need selection should use a different type of widget, such as radio buttons.

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer works, but this is the real cause.

Comment: Thanks for linking to that blog post. I never knew that "selection" didn't exist on touch screens. Or more to the point, that "selection" didn't mean what I thought it meant in this context.

Comment: Part of what's so counterintuitive here is that the ListView offers a "single choice" mode as if it were a radio group, and yet doesn't directly provide the functions expected of a radio group, like listening for when the choice is changed. I think that's why people think "selection" here means "choice."

Answer (score 3):

At first,you should set `ChoiceMode`,and then,**in ListView,there will not accept the selected event because `setOnItemSelectedListener` registed in `AdapterView`,and callback in method `handleDataChanged()`,but class `AbsListView` override this method and never callback `OnItemSelectedListener`**

[image]

you can get the seletedItem by this method in `setOnItemClickListener`

```
     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onItemClick: " + position);
            SparseBooleanArray positions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            Log.e("TAG", "onItemSelected: " + positions.toString());

        }
    });
```