# ListView onClick and onItemSelected

Tags: android, listview

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454337/why-is-my-onitemselectedlistener-not-called-in-a-listview) to fire events for my listView. I understood the concept of `OnItemClickListener`. But I have a problem. I have a listSelector drawable for my ListView. But whenever I attach the `OnItemClickListener` to the list view on click the drawable disappears. But when I attach `OnItemSelectedListener`, the drawable remains for the respective selected row whereas the `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                            int position, long id)` doesn't fire.

Any suggestion, on how to get through this problem?

Comment: Did you find any reason?