# Using button to delete selected item in Listview w/ ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've been working with Java for a few months but new to Android. This is a recipe holder app.

I have an ArrayAdapter set on a ListView and am needing to select an item in the ListView and delete it with a Button (I've already successfully set up adding of Strings to the Listview). I'm using an ArrayList for the list used to store Ingredient objects rather than a regular array. I'm attempting to use AdapterView.onSelectedItemListener to identify a user selection in the ListView and then use the Button to delete the selected item. For the Button, I'm implementing Button.onClickItemListener.

To get the list items into the ListView I'm using a dialog. I'm using an interface to send the string input from the dialog to the ListView in RecipeFragmentNew. I haven't been having issues getting the Strings from the dialog to RecipeFragmentNew, so I haven't included any of that code.

Problem: Button is deleting list items but it is deleting the first item in the list, not the item that is being selected.

**Recipe.java**

```
    public class Recipe {

    private UUID mID;
    private String mName;
    private Date mDate;
    private boolean mIsFavorite;

    private final ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;
    public final ArrayList<Instruction> instructions;


    public Recipe() {
        mID = UUID.randomUUID();
        mDate = new Date();
        this.ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        this.instructions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public UUID getID() {
        return mID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        mDate = date;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return mIsFavorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        mIsFavorite = favorite;
    }

    public ArrayList<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public ArrayList<Instruction> getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }
}
```

**Ingredient.java**

```
    public class Ingredient {

    private String name;
    private String amount;


    public Ingredient(String name, String amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "  " + this.amount;
    }
}
```

The arrayList is retreived from Recipe class using mRecipe.getIngredients().

The ListView is mIngredientWindow.

**RecipeFragmentNew.java**

```
public class RecipeFragmentNew extends Fragment implements IngredientListDialog.OnInputSelected {


public static final String TAG = "RecipeFragmentNew";
public static final String DIALOG_INGREDIENTS = "DialogIngredients";

private Recipe mRecipe;
private EditText mNameField;
private Button mIngredientAdd;
private Button mIngredientDelete;
private ListView mIngredientWindow;


private int listViewPosition;


private ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> listAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    
    UUID recipeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_RECIPE_ID);
    mRecipe = RecipeQueue.get(getActivity()).getRecipe(recipeId);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lists_detail_view, container, false);



    mIngredientDelete = v.findViewById(R.id.delete_ingredient_button);

    
    mIngredientDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               for (int i = 0; i < mRecipe.getIngredients().size(); i++) {
                if (i == listViewPosition) {
                   mRecipe.getIngredients().remove(i);

                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });

  

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mRecipe.getIngredients()
    );


    mIngredientWindow = v.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_window);
    mIngredientWindow.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            
              listViewPosition = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Button is deleting list items but it is deleting the first item in
> the list, not the item that is being selected.

The variable **listViewPosition** is always 0 because the *`setOnItemSelectedListener`* is not called. please  check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454430/7085389)
So you can replace this method with `setOnItemClicklistener` like the below code:

```
mIngredientWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //mIngredientWindow.setSelection(position);
            listViewPosition = position;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. I did end up having to change it to click listener but also needed to attach it to the List View. I have it working now. Thanks!

Comment: But in the code above i added the listener directly to the list view so it's attached

Answer (score 0):

Simple

the `listViewPosition`  variable always equals 0

Here's Why, You have defined an object from `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` but you never attache it to the listview

all you need to do is add

```
mIngredientWindow.setOnItemSelectedListener (itemSelectedListener );
```

Comment: Thank you for this!. I actually had to change it to an OnItemClickListener but I also needed to attach it the ListView as per your comment. I have it working now.

Comment: Thank you, can you please accept my comment